# Blade engine in Laravel - yield and section doesn't work

Tags: php, laravel

This is welcome.blade.php placed in views folder

```
<div class="mt-8 bg-white dark:bg-gray-800 overflow-hidden shadow sm:rounded-lg">
            <div class="grid grid-cols-1 md:grid-cols-2">
                <div class="p-6">
                    <div class="flex items-center">
                        <svg fill="none" stroke="currentColor" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-width="2" viewBox="0 0 24 24" class="w-8 h-8 text-gray-500">
                            <path d="M12 6.253v13m0-13C10.832 5.477 9.246 5 7.5 5S4.168 5.477 3 6.253v13C4.168 18.477 5.754 18 7.5 18s3.332.477 4.5 1.253m0-13C13.168 5.477 14.754 5 16.5 5c1.747 0 3.332.477 4.5 1.253v13C19.832 18.477 18.247 18 16.5 18c-1.746 0-3.332.477-4.5 1.253"></path>
                        </svg>
                        <div class="ml-4 text-lg leading-7 font-semibold"><a href="https://laravel.com/docs" class="underline text-gray-900 dark:text-white">Documentation</a></div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="ml-12">
                        <div class="mt-2 text-gray-600 dark:text-gray-400 text-sm">
                            @yield('example')
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

And this is pages/dadmin.blade.php in views folder

```
@extends('welcome')
@section('example')
<p>Laravel has wonderful, thorough documentation covering every aspect of the framework. Whether you are new to the framework or have previous experience with Laravel, we recommend reading all of the documentation from beginning to end.</p>
@endsection
```

This is routes file

```
    Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('welcome');
});
```

The yield 'example' is not wokring, the text are not being show in the welcome file. What could be the problem?

Answer (score 1):

You are returning *'welcome'* view in the route,
You should be returning the *'dadmin'* view:

```php
Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('pages.dadmin');
});
```